# Функции в php

Tags: php, функции

Имеем следующий код:

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$act = $_POST['act'];
?>
Тут форма, через которую вводим значения переменных
<?php

function calc($a,$b,$act) {

        switch ($act) {
        case "+":
            $rez = $a + $b;
            return $rez;
        break;
        case "-":
            $rez = $a - $b;
            return $rez;
        break;
        case "*":
            $rez = $a * $b;
            return $rez;
        break;
        case "/":
            $rez = $a / $b;
            return $rez;
        break;
        case "%":
            $rez = $a % $b;
            return $rez;
        break;
        default:
            return "Выберите действие";
        break;  
        }
}

$calc = calc($a,$b,$act);

echo $calc;
```

Правильно ли два раза использовать одни и те же переменные ($a, $b, $act) во входных данных и при вызове функции? Код-то работает, но хотелось бы знать, как это будет видеть php, не будет ли конфликтов в других версиях, например?

Comment: [Область видимости переменной на php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php) - почитайте внимательно, просмотрите примеры, и Вам всё сразу станет ясно.

Comment: @sereja322, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Переменные внутри функции находятся в области видимости функции, переменные за пределами функции внутри функции недоступны, поэтому конфликтов быть не может. Использовать переменные с одинаковыми названиями нормально - меньше путаницы будет, ведь имя переменной должно максимально точно говорить о том что в ней за данные хранятся.